# Compute $\sum\limits_{k+l=0}^{97}\binom{100}{k}\binom{100-k}{l}\binom{100-k-l}{97-k-l}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Compute $$\sum\limits_{k+l=0}^{97}\binom{100}{k}\binom{100-k}{l}\binom{100-k-l}{97-k-l}$$

**My Attempts**

We already khow that $\quad k+l=0 \quad$ and $\quad l=-k \quad $ so we can say that this expression actually is $$\sum_{k+l}^{97}\dbinom{100}{k}\dbinom{100+l}{l}\dbinom{100}{97}$$ luckily we can factor out $\dbinom{100}{97}$ from the sum and $$\dbinom{100}{97}\left(\sum_{k+l=0}^{97}\dbinom{100}{k}\dbinom{100+l}{l}\right)$$ my problem is about calculating this sum, do we say that $k+l=0$ always?

Or do we say that oh Ok! $k+l=0$ and now its $k+l=1$ and now $k+l=2 \cdots$

Which one is true?

And if $k+l=0$ always then how come $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and if they are not how can I use negative bases in binom?

Comment: $l$ is not equal to $-k$. $k+l$ is the value that increases

Comment: I see thanks:) Now how can I simplify this expression and how can I calculate it most importantly?

Comment: @MCCCS I actually was wondering about that. So it's all pairs of values of $k,l \geq 0$ that add up to something less than $98$?

Comment: @John Yep. So one can assume $k=0$ and solve the problem easier by just incrementing $l$.

Comment: @MCCCS And the result of this wouldn't change if we keep one variable fixed like $k=0$ (fixed)?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın Yep.

Comment: @MCCCS Thank you very much:))

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Benjamin: Please do *not* add `\limits` generally, in particular not in titles, compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/users-making-edits-by-putting-displaystyle-or-other-inappropriate-scaling-in-the.

Comment: @MartinR Ironically the post you refer to is (justly) excoriating the use of displaystyle in titles, not the use of `\limits`. You incorrectly modified an occurrence of the latter but left three (most annoying) occurrences of the former.

Comment: @Did: Here `\limits` makes the sum render as if in a displayed formula (similar to what `\dbinom` does), so the effect is similar to  `\displaystyle`. In my opinion such a change should not by made: it increases the height of the title, and possibly conflicts with the author's typographical choice. – But you are right, I just did a rollback and did not fix *all* issues.

Comment: @MartinR You should make some experiments before declaring that `\sum\limits_{n=0}^N` and `\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N` yield the same result in a title.

Comment: @Did: Both cause the limits to be positioned below/above the sum symbol, instead of next to the symbol as in inline mode.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, your point being?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65846/discussion-between-martin-r-and-did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are counting the ways of how to paint an arbitrary number $k$ of $100$ balls red, an arbitrary number $l$ of the remaining $100-k$ balls blue, and $97-k-l$ of the remaining $100-k-l$ balls green.

In the end you have simply left $3$ balls uncoloured and assigned arbitrary colours from the three available colours to all other balls.
Therefore 
$$\sum_{k+l=0}^{97}{100\choose k}{100-k\choose l}{100-k-l\choose 97-k-l}={100\choose 3}\cdot 3^{97}. $$

Comment: This is one incredible solution, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Assume $k=0$ and increment $l$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{97}\dbinom{100}{0}\dbinom{100}{l}\dbinom{100-l}{97-l}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{97}\dbinom{100}{l}\dbinom{100-l}{97-l}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{97}\frac{100!}{l!(100-l!)}\dbinom{100-l}{97-l}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{97}\frac{100!}{l!(100-l!)}\frac{(100-l)!}{6(97-l)!}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{97}\frac{100!}{l!}\frac{1}{6(97-l)!}$$

$$\frac{100!}{6}\sum_{l=0}^{97}\frac{1}{(97-l)!l!}$$

Comment: Hello @MCCCS It makes a lot of sense but I failed to find something like $3^x.\dbinom{100}{\text{something}}$ what did you get doing these calculations?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın Yes, you're right, I got stuck at $\frac{100!}{6}\sum_{l=0}^{97}\frac{1}{(97-l)!l!}$

Comment: I think before assuming $k=0$ if we say $\dbinom{100}{k+l}\dbinom{k+l}{l}\dbinom{100}{3}$ for the existing expression this explains $\dbinom{100}{3}.\cdots$ however I still can't get a power of $3$.